# Уравнение для создания поверхности типа "Капля"

Tags: математика, геометрия

Существует ли уравнение для создания капли с изогнутым хвостиком (в трёхмерном пространстве)?  Самое близкое, что я мог найти, это грушевидная поверхность с сайта wolframAlpha
(x^4 - a x^2) + a^2(y^2+z^2) = 0 (его формула)
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiriformSurface.html

Капля принца Руперта, для визуализации
[image: Капля]

Comment: Это вам, наверное, на [dxdy.ru](https://dxdy.ru/fizika-f2.html) или подобные тематические сайты. Здесь всё же математика околопрограммистская - алгоритмы да структуры данных.

Comment: Вам сюда: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: К сожалению, ваш вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. Рекомендую ознакомиться [На какиет темы можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Зонтик приношу свои извинения, я могу удалить этот вопрос?

Comment: @Генадий уже нет, так как на него есть ответ с рейтингом > 0. Пусть будет, вопрос всё-таки интересный =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, существует ли такая формула, но вывести что-нибудь такое самостоятельно вполне реально. Опишу двумерный случай, но обобщить до 3д тоже не должно быть проблем.

Задаем параметр a и график окружности с таким диаметром в центре координат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сдвигаем его правее оси ординат и избавляемся от деления.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь неравномерно исказим график так, будто наша координатная сетка и окружность на ней выглядят вот таким образом
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

После пары преобразований получается приведенная вами формула (ее двумерный вариант)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а для кривизны можно больше сжать каплю по вертикали и добавить синусоиду
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В общем, [экспериментируйте](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dvxtzgiz5c?lang=ru), что-нибудь в итоге да получится

Comment: Но вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта, тогда зачем на него отвечать?

Comment: @Зонтик 1) потому, что мне он показался интересным 2) не только мне 3) потому, что могу :)